# asp.net query string encryption generating sql reserved keyword and blocking request

Tags: asp.net, query-string, sql-injection

I am using technique to prevent sql injection in which i have list of sql reserved keywords and checking if the query string contains this reserved keyword, if yes then i am blocking the request.

My query strings are always encrypted and sometimes the encrypted string generated contains the sql reserved keywords and because of that all such requests are blocked.

How should i deal with this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

you never want to do that ... just user [Params](http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorial/AdoDotNet/lesson06) to set your data and it will automatically check keywords and the whole  sql injection process, trust me its better to use [params](http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorial/AdoDotNet/lesson06), its much safer ...